# Fuzz testing web service in development environment

Tags: devsecops

I would like to fuzz test our web services in our development environment but I do not want to pollute the database with data from the fuzz test.  We do not currently have an automated way of creating a new database and I would like to fuzz test with what we have.  How do other organizations handle this type of issue?

Comment: Perhaps creating a database instance for the duration of the test, using a snapshot of the production database might work? Just as with mocks, you can stand up a backing infrastructure with terraform or similar and then destroy it as part of the teardown stage.

Comment: Perhaps you might find chapter 13 (Testing) section 4 (Fuzz Testing) of Google's [SRS book](https://landing.google.com/sre/resources/foundationsandprinciples/srs-book/) useful.